# Considerations for securing a computer on an open LAN?

Tags: lan

Im about to move to a serviced office where they have an open LAN. Eg. no VLANs for individual companies. The room itself is locked so the main treats would be from cyber security, rather than physical.

Im trying to thing through the possible considerations for security and what i should add / amend.

Ive got a VOIP phone, which ive locked down it webGUI with a strong unique password.

The only sharing setting i have enabled on my computer is remote access via Apple Remote Desktop, which is secured with a strong unique password.

As with most people now a days all the applications we use are SSL and our email is with Google Apps for business which i understand is encrypted in transit.

I have Sophos AV Home installed on my computer.

The computer is a Macbook Pro running OSX 10.14.x

Comment: Well, you seem to know that running services is where the danger lies. There isn't much more to say about it than that: everything you expose is a risk. Try not to expose anything and look at the security of what you expose. An answer would probably have to go into each thing you could expose, which would be way too broad. I'm not sure this question is really answerable in its current form. If there is anything you are particularly interested in (e.g. "Which services are available over the network by default on OS X"), maybe you could edit your question to ask something more specific instead.

Answer (score 0):

If others can read foreign packets in the network, they could intercept your SSL traffic (it's also possible to manipulate the trust store), besides many other things (also attacking your services).
I would recommend you to consider this network as insecure and to use a VPN with good encryption in unsafe networks (so in your office network too).